# php dompdf is not rendering the html

Tags: php, joomla3.0, dompdf

Below is the function that I am using to generate the pdf file. I am loading all the required files and classes as specified in the github repository documentation.

```
public function get_invoice_converted_to_pdf(){
    try {
        // reference the Dompdf namespace
        // instantiate and use the dompdf class
        $dompdf = new Dompdf();
        $dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
        $dompdf->loadHtml('<p>hello world</p>');
        // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
        $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
        // Render the HTML as PDF
        $dompdf->render();
        // Output the generated PDF to Browser
        echo $dompdf->stream();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

It generates the pdf file but in that pdf file all I see is HTML code. Not the rendered output of that HTML.